# Angular 1.5 не обновляется ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Вывожу таблицу с помощью ng-repeat

```
<div ng-app="spApp">
<div ng-controller="spListCtrl as MyList">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="2">
        <thead>

            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>CellPhone</th>
            <th>Update</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in MyList.Contacts track by $index">

                <td class="align-center"><input type="text" ng-model="MyList.Contacts[$index].FirstName"> </input></td>
                <td class="align-center">{{MyList.Contacts[$index].Title}}</td>
                <td class="align-center">{{MyList.Contacts[$index].Email}}</td>
                <td class="align-center">{{MyList.Contacts[$index].CellPhone}}</td>
                <td class="align-center"><button ng-click="ShowNewForm(MyList.Contacts[$index])">Изменить</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Подгружаю через сервис по ajax данные

```
spApp.controller('spListCtrl', function spListCtrl($scope,dataService){

var Contacts;
  var promiseObj=dataService.getContacts();
  promiseObj.then(function(value) {

    Contacts=value; 
   });
```

Проверил в отладке, данные приходят и присваиваются нормально, но не отображаются.
 Подскажите, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
spApp.controller('spListCtrl', function spListCtrl($scope,dataService){
var self =  this
var promiseObj=dataService.getContacts();
promiseObj.then(function(value) {
  self.Contacts=value; 
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Контроллер не знает о вашей переменной, она существует только как локальная переменная функции. Заносите данные в область видимости контроллера:

```
spApp.controller('spListCtrl', function spListCtrl($scope, dataService){
    $scope.contacts = undefined;

    dataService.getContacts().then(function(value) {
        $scope.contacts = value; 
    });
}
```

Comment: Так тоже не подходит, вот решение http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018741/angular-1-5-not-update-ng-repeat

Comment: Вы в своем решении тоже заносите Contacts в область видимости контроллера.

Comment: тем не менее у меня не работало

Comment: Понятно, вы используете модель записи controller as. Я не внимательно прочитал вопрос, извиняюсь. Меня сбило с толку то, что у вас в контроллере инжектится $scope. Но сути это не меняет, просто хочу, чтобы вы понимали, что ошибка была в том, что переменная не была создана в области видимости контроллера. Используя `$scope` к списку не нужно обращаться как `MyList.Contacts` достаточно просто `Contacts`.